# CliBuilder argument without dash

Tags: java, groovy, command-line-interface

Using Groovy CliBuilder, ideally I would like to have an cmd-line as follows:

```
./MyProgram.groovy CommandName -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

Is is possible to parse pull out the CommandName as an argument using CliBuilder?

Comment: Groovy uses apache-cli, so it may not have such option.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739214/command-line-parser-and-lack-of-subcommand-and-grouping, if you are open to use some other libraries (jcommander,args4j)

Comment: @Jayan Thanks. I wanted the script to be executable from OSX cmd-line using `#!/usr/bin/env groovy`, so I ran with CliBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that if you set the property [`stopAtNonOption`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html#stopAtNonOption) to false so that the parsing does not stop in `CommandName`. Then you can get the *command* from [`CliBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html) [*options*](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html#options). A tiny example below:

```
def test(args) {
    def cli = new CliBuilder(usage: 'testOptions.groovy [command] -r -u', stopAtNonOption: false)
    cli.with {
        r longOpt: 'reverse', 'Reverse command'
        u longOpt: 'upper', 'Uppercase command'
    }

    def options = cli.parse(args)
    def otherArguments = options.arguments()
    def command = otherArguments ? otherArguments[0] : 'defaultCommand'

    def result = command
    if (options.r) {
        result = result.reverse()
    }

    if (options.u) {
        result = result.toUpperCase()
    }

    result
}

assert 'myCommand' == test(['myCommand'])
assert 'MYCOMMAND' == test(['myCommand', '-u'])
assert 'dnammoCym' == test(['myCommand', '-r'])
assert 'DNAMMOCYM' == test(['myCommand', '-r', '-u'])
assert 'defaultCommand' == test([])
```